# How to Check if a java web service is up and running in PL/SQL before calling it

Tags: java, sql, oracle, web-services, plsql

I have a PL/SQL Function that calls a java webservice. We have this java web service on 2 different machines. Lets call them 03, and 04. The same exact web service on 2 different machines just in case if one of them was down.

Right now, I have the SOAP URL hardcoded in my PL/SQL Function to call 03 always. But what I would like to do is check if 03 is up and running then go ahead and call it, otherwise check & call 04. If they are both down, then return an error states both servers are down for example.

Here is my PL/SQL Function Code:

```
        create or replace FUNCTION          "CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE" (JobID NUMBER) RETURN INT IS

        --//URL CALL
        SOAP_URL CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1000) := 'http://cdt0rwlm03.dev.gov:9001/mappownblahblah?wsdl';

        SOAP_ENVELOPE CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2000) := 
        '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://blahblah">
           <env:Header/>
           <env:Body>
              <ns1:runSeriatimValuation>
                 <arg0>$JobID</arg0>
                 <arg1>$JobID</arg1>
              </ns1:runSeriatimValuation>
           </env:Body>
        </env:Envelope>';

        --//LOCAL VARIABLES
        SOAPENVELOPE VARCHAR2(2000);
        v_Return NUMBER(1);
        REQUEST UTL_HTTP.REQ;
        RESPONSE UTL_HTTP.RESP;
        BUFFER VARCHAR2(32767);
        SOAPRESPONSE CLOB;
        XMLRESPONSE XMLTYPE;
        EOF BOOLEAN;

        BEGIN
            --// CREATE THE SOAP ENVELOPE
            SOAPENVELOPE := REPLACE(SOAP_ENVELOPE, '$JobID', JobID);

            --// MAKE THE POST CALL TO THE WEB SERVICE
            UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(3600);
            REQUEST := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(SOAP_URL, 'POST', UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQUEST, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
            UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQUEST, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(SOAPENVELOPE));
            UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQUEST, 'SoapAction', '');
            UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (REQUEST, SOAPENVELOPE);

            --// READ THE WEB SERVICE HTTP RESPONSE
            RESPONSE := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(REQUEST);
            DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(SOAPRESPONSE, TRUE);
            EOF := FALSE;

            LOOP
                EXIT WHEN EOF;
                BEGIN
                    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(RESPONSE, BUFFER, TRUE);
                    IF LENGTH(BUFFER) > 0 THEN
                        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(SOAPRESPONSE, LENGTH(BUFFER), BUFFER);
                    END IF;
                    EXCEPTION WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN 
                    EOF := TRUE;
                END;
            END LOOP;
            UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(RESPONSE);

          --// AS THE SOAP RESPONDS WITH XML, WE CONVERT THE RESPONSE TO XML
            XMLRESPONSE := XMLTYPE(SOAPRESPONSE);
            DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(SOAPRESPONSE);
          v_Return := TO_NUMBER(XMLRESPONSE.EXTRACT('//result/text()').getStringVal());
          --// DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
          RETURN(v_Return);

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SOAPRESPONSE IS NOT NULL THEN
            DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(SOAPRESPONSE);
            END IF;
            RAISE;

        END CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE;
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You'd need to call the service on 3, wait for a timeout/ error (depending on what "down" means), and then re-run the call against 4.  You'd realistically want to write a procedure that took the server name as a parameter so that you could implement that logic without repeating yourself.  But surely it would make sense to put some infrastructure between the caller and the web service that would know which server was up.  A VIP and a load balancer for example.

Comment: I'd stress the point made by @JustinCave in comment above. Use [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) for [failover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failover) scenarios. All application level solutions written by you will be inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PLSQL, you could always store the values in a small configuration table.  Something like...

```
CREATE TABLE ENDPOINT_PRIORITY
(ENDPOINT_URL  VARCHAR2(100),
 STATUS        VARCHAR2(30),
 PRIORITY      NUMBER);
```

Write a utility function that could quickly check the status of each endpoint using a simple HTTP request, update the records in the table accordingly and finally return the URL or throw an exception.

You will have performance issues if this function is being called many times per minute because of record locking and context switching however you could also implement memory caching within the session if the web service calls are synchronous.

Comment: This is just a thought - I could pass the url into the function with JobID, and then when an exception is raised I would call the function again with the new modified url (04). basically calling the function recursively only if an exception is raised. But this means 04 url will always be hardcoded in the exception. Could that work ? any feedback would be great.

Comment: Something like this: 

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error while calling Java web service from PL/SQL function: ' || SQLERRM);
 URL2 VARCHAR2(1000) := 'http://cdt0rwlm04.dev.gov:9001/mapp?wsdl';
 v_Return2 NUMBER(1);
 COUNTER = COUNTER + 1;
 
    IF SOAPRESPONSE IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- When you use FREETEMPORARY then the temporary segment in table space is released
      DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(SOAPRESPONSE);
    END IF;
 
 IF COUNTER >= 1 THEN
  RETURN;
 END IF;
 
 v_Return2 := CALL_IPVFBJAVA_WEBSERVICE(JobID, URL2);

Comment: That would definitely work however it violates one of those best practices of not coding by exception.

If you wanted to create failover code then when the exception is thrown you should have nested functions and drive it off the results from a URL table.  So a cursor would contain the results of the endpoints in the URL table and try the first one, if it returns a success code like 1 then you just break out otherwise it moves to the next record of the cursor (the next URL) and tries that one.

I can update my answer with an example if you like .